# Compare two dates in PHP pulled from SQL database

Tags: php, sql, date

I know there are many examples on Stack Overflow of how to compare two dates in PHP but I can't get my code to work properly.

Currently I have two dates the cache date and the hit date. I am trying to set it up that if the cache date is more than 2 hours ago from the hit date it will then recache new info. I currently have dates stored in MySQL in this format: `$lastcache = date("m.d.y G:i");`

My current code that works only about half the time (mostly in the later day for some reason) is this:

```
$lastcache = $row['lastcache'];
$expiredate = date("m.d.y G:i", strtotime("-120 minutes"));

if( $expiredate > $lastcache){
    cache($input);      
}else{
    //do cool stuff
}
```

How can I better compare these two dates to see if more than 2 hours has passed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code works perfectly for me, updated with your variables:

```
$interval = (strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")) - strtotime($lastcache) ) / 60;
```

This will return the time interval, in minutes. Add math to format to whatever format you want.

Assuming you kept the interval result in minutes, you would just do:

```
if($interval >= 120) {...}
```

Comment: Why'd you use `strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))` instead of `time()`? There's no need to output a formatted date and then parse it... though it is put into MySQL's format.

Comment: I have not tried it out with time() - I needed this little snippet yesterday and thought I would just post. I suppose it should work just fine with time(). OP, Let us know!

Answer (score -1):

Please consider using PHP's Date/Time object . Documentation can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)